# Distribution not found error with scrapy

Tags: command-line, package-management, python

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and have scrapy 1.-- installed. Before I started calling it from a script I could interact fine with scrapy from the command line. However since then it still works from the script but not from the commandline. 
I have not used virtualenv at all so I don't think its related to that. 
I ran the updates to scrapy and my system with apt-get and pip and the problem in the commandline persists..

The script that calls scrapy is called in a script that runs flask so there may be a link there.. (also I rebooted my system just in case there was a scrapy process that had never terminated somewhere and it didn't solve it either)

Any pointers?

This is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 5, in 
>       from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3141, in 
>       @_call_aside
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3127, in _call_aside
>       f(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3154, in _initialize_master_working_set
>       working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 642, in _build_master
>       return cls._build_from_requirements(**requires**)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 655, in _build_from_requirements
>       dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 828, in resolve
>       raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
>   pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'Scrapy==1.1.0rc1' distribution was not found and is required by the application